# Events Calendar Extension on Wordpress: jQuery is not defined

Tags: wordpress, civievent, extension

Wordpress 5.8
CiviCRM 5.40.3
CiviCRM Events Calendar - Extension 4.1

Working with the Event Calendar extension from osseed. Followed the instructions for Wordpress here:
https://github.com/osseed/com.osseed.eventcalendar

Everything seems to work as expected until you try to edit a page that's already been created with an Event Calendar shortcode. Then the console is suddenly flooded with "jQuery is not defined" errors.

Steps to recreate the error:

1. Follow Event Calendar Extension installation instructions
2. Create new page
3. Add shortcode
4. Save, publish, admire your wonderful new calendar
5. Go back and Edit the page.

Originally, I thought this might be an interaction with Elementor. But I've tested it again with the native Wordpress editor and I get the same result.

Has anyone else seen anything like this?  Any thoughts on how to proceed?

User @ajasper has provided the following screenshot which includes more details about the errors.

[image: screenshot of browser console displaying errors while stuck on elementor loading screen]

Comment: (can't comment yet) I experience the same elementor problem. Elementor pages display the calendar, but can't be edited any longer. Stuck on the loading screen with the elementor logo. 42 different errors in the browser console, mostly jquery not defined. [![screenshot of browser console displaying errors while stuck on elementor loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVKIH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVKIH.png) The shortcode actually doesn't display the calendar when used in native wordpress block pages. At least this page can still be edited, but that doesn't help much without the cale

Comment: Have either of you checked this on a vanilla site with Wordpress + CiviCRM + Event Calendar Extension? - If you can replicate some or all of it there it will be easier for community members who don't have access to Elementor to help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround:

1. Deactivate the plugin "Wordpress Event Calendar"
2. Edit your page in Elementor (this was previously impossible due to interactions between Elementor and the outdated calendar plugin)
3. Re-activate the plugin

Works like a charm.